# DOMXPath query check for div if it exists

Tags: php, domxpath

I have this code:

```
$html = '<div class="container">A<div class="wrapper">B</div>C</div>'

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class,"container")]');
```

I want to make the DOMXPath query select the `<div>` element with `class = "container"` but i want it only to select the `<div class="wrapper"></div>` when it exists. So i want it to select `<div class="container">` when `<div class="wrapper">` doesn't exist, but when it does i want it to only select `<div class="wrapper">`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As first, you can count all `<div class="wrapper">` elements via:

```
$wrapper = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class,"wrapper")]')->length;
```

if this returns **int(0)** it means, that no element with `wrapper` class has been found. With these information, we can easily modify your code to something like this:

```
$html = '<div class="container">A<div class="wrapper">B</div>C</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$wrapper = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class,"wrapper")]');

if($wrapper->length == 0) {
  // wrapper class NOT FOUND, now we can select container class
  $links = $xp->query('//div[contains(@class,"container")]');  
}

else {
  // 1 or MORE wrapper class FOUND, do something with your .wrapper class   
}
```

Comment: I have a list of `<div class="container">` and in some is a `<div class="wrapper">`.